# TypeError reading in multiline regex

Tags: ruby, regex, yaml, psych, syck

In a file is apparently stored a multiline regex, saved by `YAML::dump(b1)` without a problem.

Question, how can I load it back when Syck seems to have issues with the multiline regular expression?

```
b2 = YAML::load(File.open("browserObj.yaml", 'r'))

Syck::TypeError: Invalid Regular expression: "/\\A\\s*\n        ([a-zA-Z][\\-+.a-zA-Z\\d]*):                           (?# 1: scheme)\n        (?:\n           ((?:[\\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\\d;?:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\\d]{2})(?:[\\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\\d;\\/?:@&=+$,\\[\\]]|%[a-fA-F\\d]{2})*) \\                   (?# 2: opaque)\n        |\n           (?:(?:\n             \\/\\/(?:\n \\                (?:(?:((?:[\\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\\d;:&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\\d]{2})*)@)? \\       (?# 3: userinfo)\n                   (?:((?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\\-.]|%\\h\\h)+|\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}|\\[(?:(?:[a-fA-F\\d]{1,4}:)*(?:[a-fA-F\\d]{1,4}|\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3})|(?:(?:[a-fA-F\\d]{1,4}:)*[a-fA-F\\d]{1,4})?::(?:(?:[a-fA-F\\d]{1,4}:)*(?:[a-fA-F\\d]{1,4}|\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}))?)\\]))(?::(\\d*))?))? (?# 4: host, 5: port)\n               |\n                 ((?:[\\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\\d$,;:@&=+]|%[a-fA-F\\d]{2})+) \\                (?# 6: registry)\n               )\n             |\n             (?!\\/\\/)) \\                          (?# XXX: '\\/\\/' is the mark for hostport)\n \\            (\\/(?:[\\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\\d]{2})*)*(?:\\/(?:[\\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\\d]{2})*)*)*)? \\                   (?# 7: path)\n           )(?:\\?((?:[\\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\\d;\\/?:@&=+$,\\[\\]]|%[a-fA-F\\d]{2})*))? \\                (?# 8: query)\n        )\n        (?:\\#((?:[\\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\\d;\\/?:@&=+$,\\[\\]]|%[a-fA-F\\d]{2})*))? \\                 (?# 9: fragment)\n      \\s*\\z/x"
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck/rubytypes.rb:284:in `yaml_new'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `transfer'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `node_import'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:146:in `block in load_file'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:145:in `open'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:145:in `load_file'
    from (irb):428
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

I've seen [discussion](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1921684) about a patch to rubytypes.rb but otherwise nothing.

I'd rather not switch to Psych since that opens up another can of worms:

```
YAML::ENGINE.yamler = "psych"

# attempt to load from file again
TypeError: can't convert Fixnum into String
```

What's going on? Is there any hope? I had no prior knowledge of Syck nor Psych nor the internals of YAML parsing until this error made it non-transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the regexp as string. When you read it back from the yaml file just convert the string back into a regexp. `Regexp.new myregexp_str` - This is of course just a workaround.

**Update:**
Or you could do something that really stupid and patch psych to handle multiline regexp.
Since the patched method is to long to post it grab it [here](https://gist.github.com/4169393). 
But here is the explanation of what was really patched.

```
module Psych
  module Visitors
    class ToRuby < Psych::Visitors::Visitor
       # ...
      def deserialize
        # ... L75
        when "!ruby/regexp"
        o.value =~ /^\/(.*)\/([mixn]*)$/m # <- notice the added "m" for multiline mode
        # ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

using `ruby-1.9.3-p194`

Comment: Yes, but how would I go about doing that for any random object that is obscure to me? In this case `b1` is a webdriver `Watir::Browser` type object

Comment: I guess I don't know enough Ruby to make this transparent. I.e. how to write substitute save and load (serialize and deserialize) routines that work, giving back as close to the original object type and contents as possible.

Comment: Have you tried using `Marshal.dump` and `Marshal.load` it seems as if Marshal can handle multiline Regexps ?

Comment: I have, however Marshal won't even save this object for other reasons: `TypeError: can't dump TCPServer` so Yaml worked better for me. Good suggestion though.

Comment: Thanks; Psych had a different (more fatal) problem for me, so I think I will try to patch Syck based on your code template.  Will test and report back whatever works.

Answer (score 0):

For everybody lurking around, this looks like an old bug. I just tried with ruby 1.9.3 and I'm getting this:

`[3] pry(main)> YAML.load(YAML.dump(/asd/m))
=> /asd/m`

Comment: I'm aware of the old bug. Question is, how to go about getting it fixed in the official language or library?  Esp. something obscure or unpopular. I have little clue.

Comment: @Marcos, what is your regular expression? Dumping and loading multiline regular expressions with ruby's default YAML works for me - see in my answer body. btw specifying `m` flag does not seem necessary as it is the default in ruby.